# ngModel without looping for multiselect

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel

Using primeng created the multiselect drop down option,  option values created from the services it's listing as expected in multiselect.

ngModel has to updated and the multiselect has to selected in the multiselect drop down.

This is the response getting from as data set.

```
this.users = [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Ram",
            "emp_code": "121",
            "dpt_id": 1,
            "skills": [{id:1, rate:1} , {id:2, rate:4}, {id:4, rate:5} ]
          },
          {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Vijay",
            "emp_code": "1212",
            "dpt_id": 1,
            "skills": [{id:1, rate:1} , {id:2, rate:4}, {id:4, rate:5} ]
          },
          {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "govind",
            "emp_code": "1214",
            "dpt_id": 1,
            "skills": [{id:1, rate:1} , {id:2, rate:4}, {id:4, rate:5} ]
          }]
```

The below is the multiselect

```
this.skills = [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "php",
            "cat_id": [1]
          },
          {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "java",
            "cat_id": [1]
          },
          {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "python",
            "cat_id": [1]
          },
          {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "css3",
            "cat_id": [2]
          }]
```

Creating the skill option format

```
this.skill.push({ label: skill.name, value: skill.id });
```

The below html used to show the multi selection, how can set the ngModel value from the  users.skills variable since it has the rate value too without looping and creating the variable.

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="skill" [style]="{'width':'100%'}" [(ngModel)]="users.skills"></p-multiSelect>
```

Comment: did you try users.skills.id ??

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

You should reverse your `ngModel`,

[According to PrimeNg Documentaion](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/multiselect) `[options]` should be the array.

Also option object should contain:

```
export interface SelectItem {
    label?: string;
    value: any;
    styleClass?: string;
    icon?: string;
    title?: string;
}
```

`[options]` should be array of skills `"users.skills"` and `[(ngModel)]` should be the `skill` you want to check,

so, that **HTML** should be

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="users.skills" [style]="{'width':'100%'}" [(ngModel)]="skill"></p-multiSelect>
```

Comment: options should have field label and field key, tried getting empty drop down.

Comment: try chanhing `id` and `name` to `value` and `label`

Comment: you also have `optionLabel` property,trt this `[optionLabel] = "name"`

Comment: label works but selected not working tried [dataKey]="id"

Comment: also change,
`this.skill.push({ name: skill.name, id: skill.id });`

Comment: my understanding is that ,  
 this.user.skill has to be looped and created the separate key for each users and pushed to skill key

am I right?